# How to add title option in vue multiselect use api

Tags: javascript, vue.js

im want load title and image option in multiselect component  in vuejs
im get response from api but im not load title in multiselect
html:

```
<div class="col-md-12 mb-2">
    <multiselect id="receive-currency" @input="apiCalc" options="receive_currency">
    </multiselect>
</div>
```

js :

```
var receiveCurrency = responseData.data.direction.data[0].receiveCurrency.data.title;
                console.log("recive",receiveCurrency);
                self.receive_currency=receiveCurrency;
```

Comment: options shuld be dynamic binded(v-bind), If you want to see values after asynchronous request finish. Like that (```:options="receive_currency"```). You can read more about v-bind [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind)

Comment: @Kanow im fix this problem but i now want load all data recive to selectbox ? im use a loop but not show

Comment: you can use [v-for](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html), if you want I can write an examplefor you if you are intersted